# Unable to save the input file in hadoop

Tags: file, hadoop

I am trying to save a sample.txt file in hadoop file system using

```
./softwares/hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -put sample.txt /input
```

It is not showing any errors, but when i see in /input folder sample.txt not found.I can see only
/input folder

```
./softwares/hadoop-1.2.0/bin/hadoop dfs -ls /input
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 admin supergroup         11 2013-07-27 13:32 /input
```

In log file

```
2013-07-27 13:27:34,779 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Port returned by webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() before open() is -1. Opening the listener on 50060
2013-07-27 13:27:34,780 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: listener.getLocalPort() 
returned 50060 webServer.getConnectors()[0].getLocalPort() returned 50060
2013-07-27 13:27:34,780 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 50060
2013-07-27 13:27:34,780 INFO org.mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
2013-07-27 13:27:35,174 INFO org.mortbay.log: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:50060
2013-07-27 13:27:35,175 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: FILE_CACHE_SIZE for 
mapOutputServlet set to : 2000
2013-07-27 13:27:35,485 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-07-27 13:27:37,348 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-07-27 13:27:41,050 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-07-27 13:27:44,319 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-07-27 13:27:45,951 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-07-27 13:27:48,311 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-07-27 13:27:52,346 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-07-27 13:27:56,363 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
2013-07-27 13:27:57,619 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Failed to get system directory...
```

Can any one help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you plz show me the DN log?And where is this file present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Give complete location of your input.txt file. Use like this if it is in your current home directory.

```
[hostname]$hadoop dfs -put ./sample.txt /user/input/
```

Comment: Thanks s.singh. I can save file in hadoop by  giving like  ./bin/hadoop fs -put sample.txt /user/admin/input. here admin is my user.